# Get current URL from within a chrome.contextMenus.onClicked listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first Chrome extension and I need some help. I I think everything is working except the fact that I can't get the current URL of the tab.

```
var menu = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "extension",
    "contexts": ["all"]
  });

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var siteUrl = tabs[0].url;
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{

    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var siteUrl = tabs[0].url;
    });

    var finalUrl = "http://example.com/";

    finalUrl += encodeURI(siteUrl);

    // Open the page up.
    chrome.tabs.create(
        {
            "url" : finalUrl
        }
    );
});
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

EDIT:

Thank you for your replies. I got it working by moving

```
var finalUrl = "http://example.com/";

    finalUrl += encodeURI(siteUrl);

    // Open the page up.
    chrome.tabs.create(
        {
            "url" : finalUrl
        }
```

Inside

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var siteUrl = tabs[0].url;
    });
```

Comment: Does `document.location.href` not work?

Comment: @megawac No, that will retrieve chrome-extension://bjbdnjemkpaehlbckilllpakbphkkfme/src/bg/background.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: The code in the question and subsequent edit by the OP make it clear that the issue in the OP's implementation was a duplicate of the Async code ref question linked in the comment above. However, the accepted answer provides a solution to the situation that is sufficiently better such that I don't feel this question should be closed as a duplicate. In other words, this question is an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). The OP's implementation has the dup issue, but the best solution is to solve the actual situation, not to fix the OP's implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The info you require are provided to you already in the callback of the **[`onClicked` listener](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#event-onClicked)**.

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    // The URL of the tab (if any)
    var tabURL = tab && tab.url;

    // The URL of the page (if the menu wasn't triggered in a frame)
    var pageURL = info.pageUrl;

    // The URL of the frame (if the menu was triggered in a frame)
    var frameURL = info.frameUrl;
```

E.g. you could achieve what you want like this:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": ["contextMenus"]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
var baseURL = 'http://example.com/';

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'myMenu',   // <-- event-pages require an ID
    title: 'Do cool stuff',
    contexts: ['all']
}, function () {
    /* It is always a good idea to look for errors */
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert('ERROR: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    /* Check which context-menu was triggered */
    if (info.menuItemId === 'myMenu') {
        /* Get the URL of the frame or (if none) the page */
        var currentURL = info.frameUrl || info.pageUrl;

        /* Open a new tab */
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: baseURL + encodeURI(currentURL)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You've got a little bit of duplication in your first code block: `info.pageUrl && info.pageUrl;` should be `info.pageUrl;` (likewise for `frameUrl`. +1 for the correct way of approaching the problem though!

Comment: thank you so much, ive spent ages on this assuming it was the tab api

Answer (score 17):

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

OR if you're in a content script,

```
alert(document.location.href);
```

Comment: I neeed it to go to the variable siteUrl. I tried that and It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 8):

If you are using content script you can use

```
document.location.href
```

`document.location` is Object and can provide set of useful chunks in the URL

- `document.location.host` returns domain name ex: "http://www.google.com/"
- `document.location.path` returns the part after the domain name
- `document.location.hash` returns whatever after # symbol in the url

Comment: without a doubt, the easiest way to get the current URL. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Function:

```
function getCurrentUrl(callBackFuntion){
//you are in content scripts
    if(null == chrome.tabs || null == chrome.tabs.query){
        callBackFuntion(document.location.href);
    }else{
//you are in popup
        var queryInfo = {
            active: true, 
            currentWindow: true
        };
        chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
            var tab = tabs[0]; 
            callBackFuntion(tab.url);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Function call:

```
function alertUrl(url){
    console.log("currentUrl : " + url);
}
getCurrentUrl(alertUrl);
```

Comment: Nifty. But requires at least `"activeTab"` permission for the popup case.