# Chrome: get URL of active content script tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a content script that is run when the user connects to `"*://www.youtube.com/*"`. I need to know when the URL changes, as YouTube does not open a new 'page', so-to-speak, when you click on a link; rather it changes the URL and page contents (I think). Because of this, my content script doesn't realize that anything has changed. (I know this because it DOES work when I reload the page)

So how do I find out when the URL of the tab that my script is running in has changed?

[Edit]: My question concerns specifically getting the URL of the tab that the content script is running in, rather than getting the url of the active tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current URL for Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078989/get-current-url-for-chrome-extension)

Comment: @Fohlen, This question is not a duplicate of that question.  That question is specifically regarding getting the URL of the tab from within a `chrome.contextMenus` (which its primary answer reflects). Looking at the code from that answer it is clear that, despite there being better solutions (as answered), that question is actually a duplicate of the question listed in comments as a possible duplicate.

Comment: How did you manage to actually get this working? Specifically for the youtube case, how did you manage to detect that the page had changed?

Comment: @pingOfDoom I periodically checked the location.href, every half/full second or so.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`location.href` is a simple way to get the active URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is the simplest :)

Comment: `document.location.href` would be more precise and direct to use!! right ?

Comment: but how would you listen to change for that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your background script, you can listen for tab events and send it to your content script. An example is this,

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { tabChanged: true, title: tab.url });
  }
});
```

It checks if the tab url is being changed and then send the current url to the content script. On the content script, you can collect the information by listening for events sent by the background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
   if (message.tabChanged === true) {
    console.log("url changed")
  }
});
```